# Command raised an exception: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: discord, discord.py

я пытаюсь сделать онду команду 2 с половиной дня. пожалуйста, помогите. я хочу чтобы если пользователь уже находился в файлике - писало, что он уже в папке. код:

```
@bot.command()
async def getstart(ctx):
    await ctx.send('placeholder (welcome message here)')
    with open("config.json") as feedsjson:
        
        feeds = json.load(feedsjson)
        
        if not ctx.author.id in list(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == ctx.author.id, feeds)):
            
            await ctx.send('placeholder (we can add user in json file)..')
            getstartinsocialcredit(ctx.message.author.id, 0)
            
        else:    
            
            return await ctx.send('placeholder (user already in json file)')
```

а также в что есть в .json:

```
  "name": "995336851030290462"
}
```

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну, вам нужно `ctx.author.id` и `x['name']` преобразовать к одному типу.